# Spring GW Oauth2 Client and Spring Session Redis - Loop in authentication in round robin cluster

Tags: redis, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-session

I have a **Spring Cloud Gateway** service (**reactive version**) with **Spring Security**, which is Oauth2 client to a *PingID* service with **Authorization Code Flow**.
It is going to act as a BFF for a JS SPA client application by keeping the Oauth token (out of the web browser) and providing a Session Cookie to the browser. Something like this [example](https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/10/09/spring-cloud-gateway-oauth2-with-keycloak/).

The scenario is something like:
[image]

With the following components

- SPA application
- The BFF GW (Oauth2 client HA with a round robin policy)
- Redis cache for Session Cookies
- Secured API (Oauth2 resource server)
- PingID as Oauth and OpenID provider

**Now the BFF code and dependencies are**:

It has the followong dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
    </dependencies>
```

Here is the application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BffApplication {
  
  private static final String REDIRECT_PATH_FORMAT = "%s%s";

  @Value("${bff.client-application.host:http://localhost:8080}")
  private String clientApplicationPath;
  
  @Value("${bff.client-application.welcome-path:/home}")
  private String welcomePath;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BffApplication .class, args);
  }
  
  @Bean
  RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction() {
    return route(GET("/"),
        req -> ServerResponse
            .permanentRedirect(
                URI.create(String.format(REDIRECT_PATH_FORMAT,  clientApplicationPath, welcomePath)))
            .cookie(ResponseCookie.from("SESSION", req.cookies().getFirst("SESSION").getValue()).build()).build());
  }

}
```

Here the security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  // @formatter:off
  private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
      "/oauth2/authorization/**", "/actuator", "/actuator/**", "/auth/login",
      "/login/**", "/oauth2/**", "/callback/",  "/webjars/**",  "/error**" };
  // @formatter:on
  
  private static final String ANY_PATH = "/**";
  private static final String ANY_OF_WILDCARD = "*";

  @Value("${bff.client-application.host}")
  private List<String> allowedOrigin;

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.pathMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()).oauth2Login(withDefaults());

    http.cors();

    return http.build();
  }

  // Cors configuration to allow the frontend application as http://localhost:8080 in config
  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigin);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of(ANY_OF_WILDCARD));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of(ANY_OF_WILDCARD));
    configuration.addAllowedHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration(ANY_PATH, configuration);

    return source;
  }

}
```

And the configuration in application.yml

```
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT:8082}

management.endpoint.health:
  show-details: always
  liveness:
    include: livenessState
  readiness:
    include: readinessState

bff:
  client-application:
    host: ${BFF_CLIENT_APPLICATION_HOST:http://localhost:8080}
    welcome-path: ${BFF_CLIENT_APPLICATION_WELCOME_PATH:/home}

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  session:
    store-type: redis
    redis:
      flush-mode: immediate
      save-mode: always
  redis:
    host: localhost
    database: ${REDIS_DATABASE:0}
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
      routes:
        - id: ping-provider-ms
          uri: http://localhost:8081 # the url of the api to secure (this is oauth2 resource server)
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**
            - Method=GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS
          filters:
            - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          pingid:
            token-uri: ${TOKEN_URI}
            authorization-uri: ${AUTHORIZATION_URI}
            user-info-uri: ${USER_INFO_URI}
            user-name-attribute: ${USER_NAME_ATTRIBUTE:uid}
            jwk-set-uri: ${JWK_SET_URI}
        registration:
          pingid:
            provider: pingid
            client-id: ${CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://localhost:8082/login/oauth2/code/pingid"
            scope: 
             - openid
             - groups
             - email
```

The the issue is that we are getting an authentication loop when trying to get a secure resource the very first time when we are not logged in, and the browser doesn't have the session cookie like this scenario captured in firefox console:

[image]

It enters in a loop after entering correct user credentials, it is like doesn't finish the authentication process. This happends the first time we try to get a secured resource.

We observed that each time of the loop the created session in redis is changing.

We think this might be the root cause of the problem but we are stuck right now.

After this loop ends, we can press F5 in the browser and get the secured resource successfully, and the session is now created correctly. Although this is causing the SPA to fail.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks you all for your time and help.